# Why won't my JPanel background color change?

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe, jpanel

I have been trying to make the background of my JPanel in my frame to be black.  I can get my JButtons to show up in the panel, but the background is still not black as I set it.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have tried setting the background of the frame and all panels to background color black.  I have made sure I have set everything to be visible.  I have also tried setting setOpaque to true, which did nothing so I removed it.

This is my frame class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI frame = new GUI();
    }

    GUI(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Polygon Maker");
        DrawPane buttonPane = new DrawPane(false);
        add("North", buttonPane);
        DrawPane drawPane = new DrawPane(true);
        add("Center", drawPane);
        }
}
```

And this is my panel class:

```
    DrawPane() {
        drawPane = false;
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    DrawPane(boolean draw) {
        drawPane = draw;
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setVisible(true);
        if (!draw)
            buttonSetup();
        else {
            addMouseListener(new Drawing());
            current = new DrawPoly();

        }

    }
```

I am expecting to get a blank black frame with 3 buttons on the top, but instead I get a blank white frame with 3 buttons on the top.  I was trying to avoid the problem but now it is getting it the way of me continuing, and I have no idea what is causing the background not to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending from Jframe so you need to change how you set the color, from this

```
setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

to this way

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```